# Android Studio fails to start

Tags: android, android-studio

When I am starting `Android Studio 1.2.1` after reinstalling it, I am receiving the following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform.<init> must not be null
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform.<init> must not be null
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.<init>(Platform.java)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.getLatestPlatform(Platform.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.createSubtree(Platform.java:89)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.createComponentTree(InstallComponentsPath.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.init(InstallComponentsPath.java:215)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:233)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard.init(FirstRunWizard.java:75)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.setupWizard(FirstRunWizardHost.java:100)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.getWelcomePanel(FirstRunWizardHost.java:92)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.<init>(WelcomeFrame.java:68)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:173)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:302)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:172)
```

(original screen shot here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/3enaV.png)

I tried adding:

```
"disable.android.first.run=true"
```

to my `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\idea.properties` but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install 1.3. It appears to be a known issue and being tracked [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183063), and both devs and users report 1.3 should solve the issue

Some people report you need to clear out some files before reinstalling --

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183063#c64

Comment: does 1.3. is same of 141.2178138 ? because i cant find the 1.3 . or can you give me a link for 1.3. version ? thanks .